# how do I download a file in my current directory in ssh?

Tags: ssh

I'm looking right at the file I want to download in my current directory. wget wants a FULL url, I don't know what the full url is. im in directory /usr/local/lib/ and want to download php.ini.

I am using putty to log into my web server, and when i say donwload i want to download it from the web server to my pc

Comment: Use scp (secure copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, forget URLs, and forget wget - this file isn't going to be accessible over the world wide web (if it is, your security is seriously broken).

However, if you can see it on SSH, you can probably (depending on security policies on the server) access it by using the same credentials over SCP.

On the command-line, using [the PSCP program which comes with PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) that would look something like:

```
pscp user@server.example.com:/usr/local/lib/php.ini .
```

Or you could use a graphical client like WinSCP or FileZilla (which supports SFTP, which is another SSH-based protocol; use `sftp://server.example.com` as the server to connect to), if you're on a Windows desktop.

Comment: that would be great if i could use filezilla. Is this location accessible via ftp?

Comment: I have no idea what your server makes accessible over FTP (unlike WWW, this won't be limited to what you want the outside world to see), I suggest you experiment. However, I mentioned FileZilla because it has SCP (or SFTP) support built in - I've clarified that part of the answer.

Comment: but i was able to use your 2nd option by adding sftp:// and using a high priveledge ftp account, i was taken to the top directory and could navigate to the file and download it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use pscp which is included with PuTTY

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux:

```
scp user@server:/path2file/file path-on-localpc
```